# How do I get a reference to the underlying object in a bound DataGridViewComboBoxCell?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I don't know if my mind is not working today or if this is actually harder than I think it should be.

I've got a DataGridView with a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn bound to a generic IList of CustomObjects.  Here's a rough code sample of how I setup the column.

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn location = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn() 
{
    Name = "Location",
    DataSource = new BindingSource(GetMyLocations(), null),
    DisplayMember = "Name",
    ValueMember = "ID"
};
```

Then when I want to return the value of a cell:

```
string id = (string)row.Cells["Location"].Value;
```

But I don't want a reference to the ID property, I want a reference to the actual Location object!  I've tried not specifying a ValueMember but that appears to just use the DisplayMember.

I could iterate through all of the Location objects in the column DataSource and check for the matching ID property, however, it seems like the ComboBoxCell ought to be able to return that directly.

Also, I can't use a Dictionary in this case.

Any ideas as to the best way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `IList` of `KeyValuePair`s of "Name" and your custom object. The idea is you need `ValueMember` to point to a reference of your object. I remember having similar issues for a while with `ComboBox`es.

Something like the following ought to do the trick (off the top of my head and untested):

```
IList<KeyValuePair<String,MyObject>> comboData = 
    new IList<KeyValuePair<String,MyObject>>();

foreach(var o in GetMyLocations())
    comboData.Add(new KeyValuePair<String,MyObject>(o.Name, o));

DataGridViewComboBoxColumn location = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
{
    Name = "Location",
    DataSource = comboData,
    DisplayMember = "Key",
    ValueMember = "Value"
};
```

You might want to change `GetMyLocations()` to return the `KeyValuePair` list instead, so you're not populating two lists for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Thing
{
    public string id{  get ;  set ; }
    public string Name  {  get ;  set ; }

    //self ref
    public Thing This
    {
        get { return this; }
    }
}



form_load(){
      comboboxcell.ValueMember = "This";  // self ref
      comboboxcell.DisplayMember = "Name";
}


 datagridview1.CellValueChanged += (s, e) => {
    var cb = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dgv_titles.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
   var selectedObject  = (Thing)cb.Value  ;
}
```

thats the easieset and cleanest way ive come across.

http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2006/09/problems-with-datagridviewcomboboxcolu.html